# How can I disable MessageInspector of my condition

Tags: wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

I inpesct WCF Service With IDisptachMessageInspector and then I call service operation at BeforeSendReply Method which changes context of message. But it when I call service , Inspector runs again. I want to not run inspector. Do you know any way to do that scenerio?

Comment: What do you mean by "I call service operation at BeforeSendReply". This method is called when you are about to send the response after processing the request in your operation

Comment: Client service method which name is InsertCustomer and I inspect Message with IDispatchMessageInsepector and  using OperationInvoker I don't Invoke InsertCustomer and at BeforeSendReply Method I invoke SelectCustomer method. But Inspector runs again and  a loop happens

Comment: So you are trying to select which operation to invoke based on some criteria in the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is implementing IOperationInvoker

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a message inspector is to allow you to modify the message before or after the rest of the service model layer processes it

BeforeSendReply is called after the operation has been invoked already, AfterReceiveRequest is called before the operation is invoked.

The behavior you are seeing is that your message inspector is being fired after the operation. You are then firing another operation which then ends up calling your message inspector again. BeforeSendReply is often used to manipulate the response message to some format that WCF has problems with generating using its default serialization, etc. Its not going to be able to give you the behavior you are looking for

To decide on which operation is invoked you normally implement an [IDispatchOperationSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchoperationselector.aspx). The specific idea of this extension point looks like it will be exactly what you need